# Why are BCWP and BCWS null if the task is completed?

Tags: evm

I'm having trouble with the Budgeted Cost of Work Performed (BCWP) and Budgeted Cost of Work Scheduled (BCWS). They both appear as null, even when the tasks are 100% complete!

[image]

Comment: @MCW, both BCWP and BCWS are values to show what has or should have been completed, not what is left to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you've established a baseline and you have updated the Status Date. And check how the project is calculating EV. I believe you have two options: % complete or % physical complete. I don't think it will calculate properly using % work complete, which is what you're showing in the picture.

Comment: You can find out/edit what % complete field you are using to take EV by clicking File --> Options --> Advanced --> Earned Value Options for this Project

Comment: I'd also suggest to check Baseline Cost. If costs were added after saving baseline, then BCWP and BCWS will be always $0.00.

Comment: To add to @FranciscoAlcalá 's comment, the baseline cost should be a function of the labor hours of the resources multiplied by the cost rates of the resources, not manually entered in.